# How can we use OP_CHECKTEMPLATEVERIFY to non-interactively open channels?

Tags: lightning-network, channels, bip119-checktemplateverify

In [here](https://utxos.org/uses/non-interactive-channels/) there is a description of how to create a channel between two parties without interaction from both of them. If my understanding is correct, the transaction responsible for codifying the channel's state is transaction C in the post; in this case, my question is: since `OP_CHECKTEMPLATEVERIFY` determines the transaction in its entirety, how it is possible to later update this state?

In case my understanding is wrong, how is then the state of the channel codified?

Thanks in advance for any responses.